# Function to return true in OnClick with SweetAlert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi I'm doing a function in PHP, in which I ask for a confirmation to continue using SweetAlert, the idea is to use the onclick event, but the problem is I have no control, the message is displayed but does not expect confirmation in any of both cases, which are a form and a link.

Code:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; UTF-8" />

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="sweetalert/dist/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css">

<body>

<?php

function ShowMessage($titulo,$contenido,$tipo) {
    if($tipo=="ok") {
        //
    }
    else if($tipo=="error") {
        //
    } else if($tipo=="ask") {
echo "
swal({
  title: '$titulo',
  text: '$contenido',
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
  cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel plx!',
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
";
    } else {

    }
}

?>

<a href='http://www.google.com' onClick="<?php ShowMessage("test","test","ask"); ?>">Go</a>

<form action="http://www.google.com">
<input type="submit" name="none" text="test" onClick="<?php ShowMessage("test","test","ask"); ?>">
</form>

</body>
```

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php ShowMessage("test","test","ask"); ?>
```

Is being called on page load.

You cannot call PHP functions based on browser events without [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).

Showing a confirm message would be better done through use of JavaScript.

Try something like

```
<input type="submit" name="none" text="test" onClick="checkConfirm('test')">
<script>
checkConfirm(message) {
    var confirm = confirm(message);
    if (confirm == true) {
        // User said yes
    } else {
        // User said no
    }
}
</script>
```

**Edit**
Ah, took another look at your implementation.

Here is what you can do to achieve the result you're looking for:

```
<input type="submit" name="none" text="test" onClick="showMessage(<?php echo $titulo ?>, <?php echo $contenido ?>, <?php echo $tipo ?>)">
<script>
  showMessage(title, text, tip) {
    if (tip == 'ask') {
      swal({
        title: title,
        text: text,
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
        cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel plx!',
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
      },
      function(isConfirm){
        if (isConfirm) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

I still recommend you look up [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) and the purpose of it. It will help you wrap your head around the full stack.

Comment: thanks for the help, but it is exactly the same mistake, do not expect the true.

Comment: What issue are you still experiencing?

Comment: Sweetalert message is displayed but does not wait for confirmation and redirects the user to the page marked